# Laravel database seeder not seeding everything in docker,

Tags: laravel, docker

I am experiencing a very weird situation where a simple seeder seeds everything in my default environment (13999 database entries and shows `Database seeding completed` success message.) but stops at 6400 entries (doesn't show the success message) when running in docker. I don't know even where do start de debugging process.

Seeder code:

```
$fp = gzopen(database_path() . '/seeders/cars.json.gz', 'r');
        try {
            $i = 0;
            while ($json_text = fgets($fp)) {
                $json = json_decode($json_text, true);
                DB::table('cars')->insert([
                    'full_name' => $json['full_name'],
                    'slug_name' => $json['slug_name'],
                    'year' => $json['Ano'],
                    'model' => array_key_exists('model', $json) ? $json['model'] : null,
                    'name' => $json['name'],
                    'brand_id' => Brand::where('name', $json['brand'])->first()->id,
                    'content' => $json_text,
                    'created_at' => new \Datetime(),
                    'updated_at' => new \Datetime()
                ]);
                echo "Inserted " . ++$i . " cars\n";
            }
        } finally {
            fclose($fp);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the `while` method inside a DB transaction:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    // your while logic
}
```

Also, no logs show up on `/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion without success. No logs showing in /storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: @Kos-Mos try to remove `Brand::where('name', $json['brand'])->first()->id` and add the ID `1` in it's place (just a quick test). You shouldn't be querying 14k times to get the ID of a brand too, use an hash map for example (`$brands = Brand::all(); $brandsMap = []; foreach($brands as $brand) { $brandsMap[$brand->brand] = $brand->id }` and then use `$brandsMap[$json['brand']]` inside the insert query.

Comment: the problem was memory_limit in docker's php. thx for your help